# How do I create a shared disk for a cluster running under Hyper-V in an Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v, shared, disk, windows-clustering

I've spent ages going around in circles on this so I'm hoping someone will point me in the right direction.

I'm creating a SQL Server lab running under Hyper-V on an Azure Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Gen 1 virtual machine. So far so good as I've got an AG running on two replica VMs, however I want to expand the lab to inlude a Windows Failover Cluster so I need to be able to create a shared disk and that's where I'm stuck. Whenever I try and add a shared disk in the Hyper-V Manager (or PowerShell) I get the following error:

**The storage where the virtual hard disk is located does not support virtual hard disk sharing**

It can't be the type of Azure disk I'm using as I get the same problem trying to create the Hyper-V shared disk on a Standard HDD, Standard SSD and Premium SSD with sharing enabled so what else do I need to do?

Regards,

Gordon.

Comment: Have you referred this : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82de3d1e-668e-4cde-93d9-8595b0dd0bf8/the-storage-where-the-virtual-hard-disk-is-located-does-not-support-virtual-disk-sharing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below possible solutions:

- Please check if you have enabled the Sharing while creating the managed disk in the portal. If not then please enable it while deploying and add the max shares as per your requirement .

[image]

**Reference:**

[Share an Azure managed disk across VMs - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared#disk-sizes)

[Enable shared disks for Azure managed disks - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared-enable?tabs=azure-portal)

- Please try to attach the VHDx file to IDE controller as its a Gen 1 virtual machine because only the SCSI controller has the option "virtual hard disk sharing" and Gen 1 VM only can boot from IDE.

**Note:** Please do not use this feature without CSV or Scale-Out File Server with SMB 3.0 on file-based storage .

[image]

**Reference :**

[the storage where the virtual hard disk is located does not support virtual disk sharing (microsoft.com)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82de3d1e-668e-4cde-93d9-8595b0dd0bf8/the-storage-where-the-virtual-hard-disk-is-located-does-not-support-virtual-disk-sharing)

Thank you [Prabhu Dutta Mohanty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16279655/prabhu-dutta-mohanty) for providing the reference link .

Note: If the issue is still not resolved , Please create a support request to Azure support from portal (Support+Help) for assistance.